# flutter: How to make text in row without overflow in one or two line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have this image, In this image I have contact section.
I want to make like this.

```
Row(
  children: [
    // Flexible(
    //   child: RichText(
    //     // textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    //     text: TextSpan(
    //         text: "Contact: ",
    //         style: textStyleWith12500(
    //             MyColor.blackColor),
    //         children: <TextSpan>[
    //           TextSpan(
    //             text:
    //             "$outletEmail",
    //             style: textStyleWith10400(
    //                 MyColor.darkGreyColor),
    //           ),
    //         ]),
    //   ),
    // ),
        Flexible(
          child: Text("Contact: ",
              style: textStyleWith12500(
                  MyColor.blackColor)),
        ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        "$outletEmail",
        style: textStyleWith10400(
            MyColor.darkGreyColor),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,right: 5),
          height:10,child: VerticalDivider(color: MyColor.blackColor,width: 2)),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        "$outletContact",
        style: textStyleWith10400WithUnderLine(
            MyColor.blueColor),
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can add a `FittedBox` if the width is constrained. This widget will automatically resize the text to fit in one line.

```dart
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Text('Your Text'),
   ),
);
```

Another way is to specify `maxLines` in `Text` widget and specify overflow style.

```dart
Text(
  'your text',
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Expanded` widget inside your `Row` widget. `Flexible` widget won't force its content's width to its parent width.

In my opinion, `Expanded` widget with `RichText` will be perfect in your case.
check this code:

```
Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: RichText(
                  text: const TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 19,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      text: 'Contact : ',
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(text: 'Sam@smith.com,'),
                        TextSpan(text: 'example@domain.com'),
                        TextSpan(
                            text:
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua')
                      ]),
                ))
              ])
```

This will automatically adjust to the device width and wrap lines accordingly. If you need ellipsis on overflow, it can achieved by adding maxLines and overflow behaviour.
Here's the dart pad screenshot [image]

[dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f2a8bf0c16150b25697c738020f9be8b)

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        'Your long text goes here, and it should wrap within one or two lines without overflowing.',
        maxLines: 2, // Set the maximum number of lines
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Display ellipsis (...) when text overflows
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexible or expanded widget.

```
Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  'Your text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 2, 
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                 
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Expanded widget along with other widgets to ensure that text doesn't overflow in one or two lines.

```
       Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'add your text ',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

i hope it's a use-full for you.